# Make group of inputs' values don't exceed a specified value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a game and using JavaScript/jQuery to spend points of character's attributes. I have six inputs like this one, each representing one attribute:

```
<input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
```

And one input like this (the "pool"):

```
<input id="pool" type="number" min="0" max="36" step="1" value="36" readonly>
```

The last input functions as a "pool", which means that it is the total of remaining points to be spent on the group of the six inputs. I would like to have a following:

- Changing the any of the "attributeVal" inputs subtracts or restores points in the pool, which cannot be more than 36 and less than 0.
- Each input from "attributeVal" cannot be less 1 and more than 36.
- "attributeVal" and "pool" cannot be negative.

I've tried different approaches, but couldn't prevent player from exceeding the values beyond the pool maximum, mostly because I don't know how to prevent the change event.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script>
    let attributeVal = $(".attributeVal");

    attributeVal.on("change paste keyup", function (e) {
        let prev = $(this).data('val');
        let maxPointsOverall = 42;
        let spentPoints = 0;
        let poolInput = $('#poolInput');

        $(".attributeVal").each(function () {
            spentPoints += +$(this).val();
        });

        if ((maxPointsOverall - spentPoints) < 0) {
            $(this).val(prev);
            poolInput.val(0);
        } else {
            poolInput.val(42 - spentPoints);
        }
    });

    attributeVal.on("cut copy paste", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Could you please give me any hints, how I can make this one work?

```js
let attributeVal = $(".attributeVal");

attributeVal.on("change paste keyup", function(e) {
  let prev = $(this).data('val');
  let maxPointsOverall = 42;
  let spentPoints = 0;
  let poolInput = $('#poolInput');

  $(".attributeVal").each(function() {
    spentPoints += +$(this).val();
  });

  if ((maxPointsOverall - spentPoints) < 0) {
    $(this).val(prev);
    poolInput.val(0);
  } else {
    poolInput.val(42 - spentPoints);
  }
});

attributeVal.on("cut copy paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="font-weight-bold unselectable mb-3">Points available
  <input id="poolInput" type="number" min="0" max="36" step="1" value="36" readonly>
</label>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Strength
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Endurance
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Dexterity
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Perception
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Intelligence
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Charisma
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
```

[Here is JSFiddle to illustrate the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Bloodlex/rf6u723w/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue is that, once the input event has been fired, you can't reset it to the previous number without saving the state of every input somewhere, which is a bit messy. You might consider first validating the value:

- Make sure it's an integer between 0 and 36
- Count up the number of points spent on *other* attributes. Make sure the current value, when added to that, is no more than the `maxPointsOverall`. (If it overflows, reduce the current value to the point such that `pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs + newVal === maxPointsOverall`)

Then set the current value to the validated `newVal`, and calculate / populate the value for the `#poolInput`.

To make sure the inputs get fixed immediately, rather than on a short delay, add an `input` listener (which will fire around keypress, rather than on keyup):

```js
const attributeVal = $(".attributeVal");

attributeVal.on("change paste keyup input", function(e) {
  let newVal = Math.floor($(this).val());
  newVal = Math.max(1, newVal);
  newVal = Math.min(36, newVal);
  const maxPointsOverall = 42;
  let pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs = 0;
  $(".attributeVal").not(this).each(function() {
    pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs += +$(this).val();
  });
  if (newVal + pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs > maxPointsOverall) {
    // Invalid, reset these points to the maximum allowable:
    newVal = maxPointsOverall - pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs;
  }
  // New value has been validated, put it into the DOM:
  $(this).val(newVal);
  const pointsLeft = maxPointsOverall - (pointsSpentOnOtherAttribs + newVal);
  $('#poolInput').val(pointsLeft);
});

attributeVal.on("cut copy paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="font-weight-bold unselectable mb-3">Points available
  <input id="poolInput" type="number" min="0" max="36" step="1" value="36" readonly>
</label>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Strength
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Endurance
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Dexterity
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Perception
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Intelligence
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Charisma
    <input class="attributeVal" type="number" min="1" max="36" step="1" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for this incredibly fast answer! Now I see it's a bit more complicated as I thought... I like the solution, but is there any way to stop the unwanted value from appearing for a short time before it is reset to the correct one? But if it is not possible, I'd go with that what you posted :)

Comment: Use an `input` listener instead - it'll fire around keypress, not keyup

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!